# Can (this) throws a NullPointerException?

Tags: android

I have an Activity with checkbox that triggers onCheckedChanged(), and I initializing it by using.

```
setContentView(R.layout.signup_welcome);
CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_accept);
check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

what weird is it works but there is a time that it caused NullPointerException. Should I use (MainActivity.this) instead of (this) only? Is there a difference between the two?

one thing I have the same id's in different layout. Should it be the caused? but I think that is fine because I'm using a View.

logs:

Comment: if `check` is `null`, 100% it will throw `NullPointerError`

Comment: yes if `check` is null

Comment: "this" cannot be null. It is surely "check" which is null here

Comment: I declare check like this  CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_accept); how it supposed to be null?

Comment: Are you sure, there IS a view with this ID?

Comment: one thing I have the same id's in different layout. Should it be the caused? but I think that is fine

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation for findViewById. you'll find it can return null, and in which cases.

Comment: Post some more code so that one can get exact idea

Comment: @GangnaminmoAko Upload also the layout file. If said layout file contains `checkbox_accept` and findViewById() still returned `null`, I would recommend to clean the project

Comment: nope this is Activity so I just used setcontentView

Comment: you should provide the stacktrace of the NPE if you are still confused. you might be looking in the wrong place. Alternatively add an `if (check == null)` clause for debugging and see when that happens.

Comment: Using the same id in different layouts makes no difference here. You can even use the same id multiple times in the same layout and `findViewById` will return the first `View` that it finds (**only** the first `View`)

Answer (score 1):

`this` won't throw a `NullPointerException`, however `check` could be `null` and invoking a method on it would then throw a NPE.

Comment: I declare check like this CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_accept); How it supposed be null?

Comment: `check` can be `null` if the view is not found. Check you are referring to the correct resource in the layout.

Comment: how can it not be found because it works in several times but there is also a time that it throws NPE without any changes

Answer (score 0):

Either `check` view has no reference or you didn't implement `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface in your `Activity`.

Comment: Not implementing the interface would result in a compile time error, not a runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you are inflating your layout **before** calling `findViewById`. If you're in an `Activity`, you should use `setContentView`, if you're extending a `View`, use a `LayoutInflater`.

Then, you need to make sure that a `View` (`CheckBox` in your case) with that id is present in your layout.

Then, you need to make sure that the `id` (resource id) passed to `findViewById` matches the one in the layout file.

If the above fail, try doing a fresh clean/build (sometimes `R` is not regenerated/redeployed on the device/emulator when you're only editing the layout XML).

Comment: yes all of the way that you mentioned are all in proper. Please keep in mind that it works but there is only a time that it throws NPE without any changes.

Comment: on the same device/emulator?

Comment: If you are not removing the `View`, the above *should* work, as `setContentView` is blocking. The only time I've had issues with retrieving a `View` using `findViewById` was when Eclipse+Android SDK weren't regenerating/redeploying the `R` class in the apk. I've found this out by comparing the constant id in the code shown in the debugger against what was in my current source code and what was in the source code from the repo. Either way, a simple clean/build (autobuild turned off) or should work. Otherwise, you can try regenerating `R` by deleting it from the `gen` folder and rebuilding.